# What replacement florescent lamps can I use?

Tags: lighting, kitchens

One of the lamps has gone on the under cabinet lighting in our kitchen. I did have a big stack of spare florescent tubes I bought some years ago.

But now looking on the internet I can't find any replacements?

The only markings I have on the lamps are LT 15W/530-030 made by Narva.

We have quite a big kitchen and a total of 6 of these lights.

What should I be looking for in a replacement bulb?

Answer (score 1):

```
Narva Specs
LT 15W/530-030, 15W, Warm White 530 color rating, 438mm long, G13 Socket, 26mm dia.

Satco Specs
F15T8-530, 15W, Warm White 3000 Kelvin, 451.61mm MOL, G13 Socket, T8 1"/25.4mm dia.
```

So, we have a lamp with the following specifications:

T8 15 Watt 1"/25.4mm dia tube with ANSI G13 medium BiPin socket having a 3000 kelvin Warm White color rating and a CRI (Color Rendering Index) of 50 that is nominally 18"/455mm long.

So, basically look for the following tubes and check the length. Narva measures from end cap to end cap while Satco uses **Maximum Overall Length** which includes the pins in the length.

```
Common designation
F15T8-530
F15T8-WW

Philips
F15T8/WW/ALTO

OSRAM Sylvania
F15T8/WW
```